# Why does Captain Jack Sparrow suffer from the curse?

Tags: plot-explanation, curse-of-the-black-pearl, pirates-of-the-caribbean

As told in the Curse of the Black Pearl, Captain Jack Sparrow faces mutiny by his crew members and is abandoned on an island before the mutineer crew find a chest of cursed coins.

How is it then possible that he ends up being cursed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually Captain Jack Sparrow **didn't get cursed** when his old crew found the Aztec gold.

What you may be thinking of is the point in the movie where Jack becomes undead for short time. In the cave, while Barbossa and Jack negotiated, **Jack stole one Aztec coin** from the chest getting himself cursed until he returned it.

[Here](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Cursed_crew) you can read fairly detailed plot in case you missed something.

Answer (score 10):

He wasn't cursed, to begin with, it was only near the end of the film when he takes a coin directly from the chest that he gets cursed.

Answer (score -1):

Jack was not cursed, to begin with, but once he persuaded Barbossa to ally himself and not kill Will, he picked up 4 coins and threw back 3 to dramatically say "every" (throws down coin) "last" (throws down coin) "One" (throws down coin). This was a trick to make It seem like he replaced all coin directly back to the chest without really taking any BUT he had a fourth coin and the camera shows him slyly palming it and extending his fingers to indicate an empty hand, classic gamblers trick. He then stepped away from the chest which in turn would curse him. Another factor to this plan working is that the rest of the pirates loathe the curse having been under it for so long, It probably didn't occur to them that someone would deliberately allow themselves to be cursed just to be temporarily unkillable.

The main reason Jack did this isn't necessarily that he was worried he'd die in general but he knew he'd have to fight Barbossa who has been suggested to be even better than him at swordplay.

To answer some above suggestions that Jack was Immortal since before then, no he wasn't.

One of the crew saying "you're supposed to be dead" was In reference to him being left on an Island to die but only Jack knew It was a regularly stocked point for merchants. No doubt knowledge from his days working for the East India Trading company and Jack Is known to keep his cards close to his chest.

The apple he ate wasn't finished, Barbossa took it before he had Jack locked up. Barbossa inspected the apple and angrily threw it away. This, coupled with the fact Jack rummaged through the apples on the table suggests that Barbossa isn't in the habit of poisoning all of the apples, only the top ones, and Jack knows his methods having been crewmates and friends.

Additional note: Jack and Barbossa are solid friends but It is likely the curse made Barbossa unusually ruthless to get what he wanted. He said he felt nothing, what would this say of his conscience? There probably wouldn't be one, hence why when he was alive again he was far more amicable with Jack, had his honour and "sense of fair play".

Answer (score -3):

So the apples aren't poisoned! Barbosa can't eat because he said everything he eats turns to ash! The reason the crew says you're supposed to be dead is that he was left on that desert island and he managed to escape but they left him there for dead!

Jack wasn't cursed because they did the mutiny before Jack got to the treasure! He then takes a coin from the chest so he can't die in the battle with Barbosa at the end, it figures that out in the jail- it's implied!

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer doesn't answer the original question being asked.  It seems like you are commenting on one of the other answers given.  The second paragraph of your answer seems to provide an answer that has already been given and accepted by the OP.

Answer (score -4):

Even though jack sparrow clearly wasn't cursed until he took the gold on the isle of (something hard to spell/pronounce) there are a few misleading scenes where it hinted at him being dead or undead or cursed (whatever it is). When he ate the poisoned apple and showed no symptoms of being poisioned and where some pirate said to him "your spose to be dead" and he responds "am I not?"

Comment: What poisonous apple? *"and where some pirate said to him "your spose to be dead" and he responds "am I not?""* - I don't think that was to hint on a curse, though.

Comment: I don't recall any apple being poisonous in the movie.  Further, they say he should be dead because they stranded him on what they thought was a completely desolate island.  We then learn further in the movie that it has a cache of food and Jack got off the island safely..or as he says "Sea Turtles".